# how to find ppa location for bitcoin- 0.15.1-zesty1

Tags: ppa, location

I am trying to install the reference package via "sudo-add-apt-repository ppa:" but whatever I try to enter in the location is wrong. I don't see the location anywhere in the package description.  Please direct me as to how to discover the ppa location. Thank you.

Comment: I have also tried the following:

Comment: What leads you to believe that such a PPA exists?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin

Comment: The location is on that page, in the section *below* the description called "Adding this PPA to your system". Just tried it - works.

Comment: i did those commands earlier  and it did not work for me.  If it worked for you, I must have some other issue.  Consider this closed.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You have mis entered the command - you entered `sudo-add-apt-repository ppa:` but the correct command is shown below.  These commands should be entered in a terminal window.  To open a terminal press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt update
sudo apt insall bitcoin-qt bitcoind
exit
```

The first command adds the repository, the second updates repository lists on your computer.  The third command installs bitcoid-st and bitcoind, and the final command closes the terminal window.